# Terminal doesn't show the server name after using ssh - Centos7

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, centos

Please notice that I don't have any problem with hostname and I can change the hostname by configuring /etc/hostname , and it is easily shown on the terminal.

**My problem:**
I just setup two servers on CentOS 7, they are not real servers of course, but when I connect to them using ssh, the hostname doesn't replace by server name and it still shows me `root@localhost` on the terminal instead of `root@server1` OR `root@server2` .

The hostname is localhost.localdomain.

**/etc/hosts:**

```
27.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

192.168.122.1   server1.exampert.com    server1

192.168.122.2   server2.exampert.com    server2
```

**/etc/hostname:**

```
localhost.localdomain
```

This question has not been answered. my problem is with hostname which comes after root@ on the terminal when I use ssh command! if I change /etc/hostname or other commands, hostname changes on the terminal as well, but when I use `ssh server1` the hostname is still as it was before using the ssh command! I expect it to be `root@server1` instead of `root@localhost~`

What could be the problem?

[ScreenShot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2L7x.jpg)

Comment: have you edited something in your profile? Also whats in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: what do you mean by profile? 
this is the `resolv.conf` file:

`search localdomain exampert.com`
`nameserver 192.168.245.2`
`nameserver 8.8.8.8`
`nameserver 8.26.56.26`
~

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting hostname via hotnamectl?

```
hostnamectl set-hostname your-new-hostname
```

in order for the change to take effect you have to reboot the machine.

Comment: As I said I can change the hostname w/o any problem, it would be appeared in the terminal.